# How to get the new data of Norm or Gev distribution fitting?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, normal-distribution

I want to finish a chi-square test between initial data and new data. The new data of Norm or Gev distribution fitting. Now,I don't know how to get the new data. Thank you for reading my question

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some time to read **[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. I also recommend to have a look at this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: So sorry,i should study how to ask and i had solved the question.Thanks a lot.